# How to open a new window in tkinter python 3.7 having same functions as that of original window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7

I am working on code in tkinter python v3.7 where I want to open a new window which has same functionalities like original window. How can I do that?

While searching for solution I came across function naming Toplevel which creates new tkinter window. But this new window is completely new, It doesn't have functionalities(Button, geometry size in my case) which were provided in original one.

```
from tkinter import *
class TextPad:

    def new_window(self):
        top = Toplevel()

    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title('Text Pad')
        master.geometry('400x400')

    self.button = Button(master, text='Press', 
                             command=self.new_window)
    self.button.pack()

root = Tk()
t = TextPad(root)
root.mainloop()
```

My original window has geometry size of '400x400' and It has 'button', I want to open a new window having this functionalities.

Comment: `TextPad(Toplevel())` . if you want identical window then you have to use again `TextPad()` but this way use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want two (or more) windows at the same time.

If you want identical window then use again `TextPad()`

but this time use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`

```
def new_window(self):
    top = TextPad(Toplevel())
```

and don't run second `mainloop()`

---

If you want replace first window by new window - to have alwasy only one window - then you would have to destroy old window and then create new one using `TextPad()` with `Tk()` and `mainloop()`

But it would need to use `self.master` instead of `master` to have access to `master` in method `new_window`

```
from tkinter import *

class TextPad:

    def new_window(self):
        self.master.destroy()

        root = Tk()
        t = TextPad(root)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Text Pad')
        self.master.geometry('400x400')

        self.button = Button(self.master, text='Press', 
                             command=self.new_window)
        self.button.pack()

root = Tk()
t = TextPad(root)
root.mainloop()
```